# Have two tables A,B that has one to many relationship. I want to link A to B by only taking the most recent instance in B

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many

I have two tables, A and B.  For a particular value in A in a particular column there will be multiple rows in B that correspond to it.  I want to extract the info from B, but not all the rows but just the most recent.

What is the eastiest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Which platform? MySQL, Oracle, different one? Put it into tags.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to do this is to use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function.  Here is a sketch of what the query might look like:

```
select *
from a left join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by b.aid order by b.date desc) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on a.aid = b.aid and b.seqnum = 1;
```

You can also approach this with aggregation:

```
select *
from a left join
     b
     on a.aid = b.aid join
     (select b.aid, max(b.date) as maxdate
      from b
     ) bmax
     on b.aid = b.aid and b.date = bmax.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `B.id` is `AUTO INCREMENTED` and `B.a_id` references A, you can

```
SELECT B.id,B.a_id,B.data FROM A
JOIN B
ON B.a_id = A.id
WHERE B.id IN (
  SELECT MAX(B.id)
  FROM B
  GROUP BY B.a_id  
)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2af88/6). I'm assuming PostgreSQL here, but I'm sure you can adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the rows are only added and not updated and the IDs are not recycled numbers, then you can selects the record from B with highest number.

If you are able to edit the schema, then put last lastUpdatedTime column into B and select according to column.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain you by giving example.

Suppose your A table is for `ORDERS` & B is for `PRODUCT DETAILS`

In your A table always one value will going to insert at a time.
But you cant have many products at a time in a single order 
So this is the general scenario where we need to get the most updated records from the database.

There are 2 ways :

`1.` On creation of order Insert one date into database & get updated records by using the date.

`2.` Auto incremented ID is the other option last ID will be your most updated records.

**But Most standard way is to use Date column in the database.**